# Conservation of momentum in Heisenberg's microscope

Tags: quantum-mechanics, thought-experiment

In working through Heisenberg's microscope, conservation of momentum for the photon and electron tells us that

\begin{align}
\frac{h}{\lambda}=\frac{h}{\lambda'}\sin\theta+p_x\,,
\end{align}
where the angle $2\theta$ subtends the arc of the lens (for a diagram, see pg. 147 of Capri [here](https://books.google.ca/books?id=NMMgMI2kGnQC&pg=PA146&dq=%22of%20the%20microscope%20is%20of%20finite%20width%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CCYQ6AEwAGoVChMIi_jTkauBxwIVT0aICh3Asw_G#v=onepage&q=%22of%20the%20microscope%20is%20of%20finite%20width%22&f=false)), $\lambda'$ is the photon's wavelength from Compton scattering, and $p_x$ is the momentum of the electron.

Is there a reason why it is usually assumed that $\lambda\approx\lambda'$? Is it because Heisenberg's microscope is a rough argument to demonstrate the physical motivation of the uncertainty principle, so it is not productive to to include higher order terms dependent upon the Compton wavelength?